# oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement error in java application

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

When I try to insert some values from a jsp page into oracle database, sometimes I get exception that prohibits the insertion. But I do not get this error most of the time I try to insert values in database from that page. exact error stack trace is:

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement@cca76d
    at repaircenter.common.Inbound_Inspection.insert_prio(Inbound_Inspection.java:403)
    at repaircenter.actions.Inbound_ACTIONS.runAction(Inbound_ACTIONS.java:84)
    at com.ge.appl.tsf.kernel.TSFBaseAppController.runActions(Unknown Source)
    at com.ge.appl.tsf.kernel.TSFBaseAppController.runRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.ge.appl.tsf.shells.common.TSFCommonDispatcher.runRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.ge.appl.tsf.shells.web.TSFDispatcher.runRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.ge.appl.tsf.shells.web.TSFDispatcher.service(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at repaircenter.common.listingObjects.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve.invoke(FastCommonAccessLogValve.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:307)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:385)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:748)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:678)
    at org.apache.jk.common.SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:871)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Can anybody please help me on what could be the possible issue? thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give us the Querry

Comment: What is your Oracle database version and JDBC driver version? Is your JDBC driver is compatible with database version?

Comment: I cannot give you the exact query right now. sorry for that. Only i can say,that the same query(with different attributes) runs many time successfully. But sometimes it get stuck for some particular values for a particular field.Suppose, there is a field in database named empid which is an attribute in the query. The problem is oneday the query throws the error for lets assume empId 5565434.But if you cahnge the empid like 5565435, then it will run. but for that number it wont run.

Comment: I am using Oracle JDBC Driver version - 9.0.2.0.0 and oracle 11i database. Please let me know if you require something else. Thank you in advance. I am looking forward for your help.